# Create PDF file with pre-defined template

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfkit, pspdfkit

I am trying to create a PDF with the pre-defined template with this particular library called PDFKIT. The server is written in Nodejs, may I know is there any good example I could refer to? What I want to achieve is to have a User Interface as an entry form, and then there is a pre-defined PDF file in-place on the server.When the user hits the submit button, the pdf rendering engine will pick-up the data and embedded into the pdf template file.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the PSPDFKit for Web / PSPDFKit Server [API docs for handling forms](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/server/current/api/forms/) which let you retrieve and update all form fields. You can then use the [document APIs](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/server/current/api/documents/#toc_fetching-a-document-s-pdf-file) for downloading a PDF with the form fields set to whatever values your user submitted.

So to recap, the steps are:

1. [Upload the template PDF to the server](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/server/current/api/documents/#toc_uploading-a-document) storing the document id in your database or in the user's session.
2. [Fill in the form fields](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/server/current/api/forms/#toc_updating-form-field-values) using the data your user submitted.
3. [Download the PDF](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/server/current/api/documents/#toc_fetching-a-document-s-pdf-file) with the updated form fields and e.g. email it or store it somewhere.

Alternatively you can [create a signed URL so that you can directly redirect your user to the generated PDF](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/web/current/server-backed/document-api/#toc_download-a-document-as-pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about PhantomJS? There is a package which name is phantom-html-to-pdf. You may give it a try.

Comment: I have but I can not access the repo right now but I think you can follow this page http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html